# Mutiple shared layout mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Suppose I have under Shared folder `_Footer.cshtml` and `_Nav.cshtml` layouts, and I want to add both to my main html, like:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Nav.cshtml";
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible.

You can use `Html.Partial()` to render Views as partial Views

Let's say you have these views in your shared folder: `~/Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml`, `~/Views/Shared/_Nav.cshtml` views, and you want to add them to the main layout,

Then you can use them in the main layout as

```
@Html.Partial("_Footer")
```

and

```
@Html.Partial("_Nav")
```

***NOTE:***

using the code below

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Nav.cshtml";
```

is just the reassigning the Layout to different values or views, you need to locate the portion of your code in your main layout where you need the `Footer.cshtml` and `Nav.cshtml` views and add them as Partial Views

Comment: When I add `@Html.Partial("_Footer")` I'm getting `The file "~/Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml" cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderBody" method` error

Comment: The error is clear, please remove `@RenderBody` from the file. Render body is used to render the view you want to render in a layout, the portion render body is where the view renders